# Category slug - Custom post type Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

With custom post type, i need to use category slug for my class (css).

```
<?php 
            global $post;
            $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'typeresources');
            if ($terms) {
                $output = array();
                foreach ($terms as $term) {
                if ($term->term_id != 14)
                {
                $output[] = '<div class="cat-resources">' .$term->name .'</div>';
                }
                }
                echo join( ' ', $output );
            };
            ?>
```

Would like to add at my "cat-resources class" the categroy slug

How can i do that ?

Comment: What is your category slug?

Comment: @Bhautik taxonomy slug

Comment: `$output[] = '<div class="cat-resources '.$term->slug.'">' .$term->name .'</div>';` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go.

```
global $post;
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'typeresources');
if ($terms) {
    $output = array();
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        if ($term->term_id != 14) {
            $output[] = '<div class="cat-resources '.$term->slug.'">' .$term->name .'</div>';
        }
    }
    echo join( ' ', $output );
};
```